# How to retrieve just messages of an event from the event log?

Tags: powershell

Per example, using:

```
Get-EventLog system -newest 5 -After 09202016 -Message "Something",
```

Am thinking "Something" could be the type of message that am looking for.

Though I do not get any matches:

```
Get-EventLog : No matches found
At line:1 char:13
+ Get-EventLog <<<<  system -newest 5 -After  09202016 -Message The
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:) [Get-EventLog], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetEventLogNoEntriesFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetEventLogCommand
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use wildcards:

```
Get-EventLog system -newest 5 -After 09202016 -Message "*Something*"
```

Comment: Thank you, that works great, really helpful if need to search for a specific type of message.